# Backup registry with rsync

Tags: linux, windows-10, backup, rsync

I'm in the process of setting up a backup procedure on a Windows 10 Home/Kubuntu 16.04 dual boot system using rsync.

I have created a virtual machine, which has these OS-es, and from the Windows subsystem for Linux launched rsync to copy the folders of the system drive to another. Then I booted into Ubuntu formatted my Windows drive, and copied the backed up files back.

Then I attempted to boot into Windows, but it was unsuccessful, because it couldn't find the registry. I have found out, that rsync was unable to copy the registry hives. I'm also unable to copy them in Windows Explorer. In Windows Explorer I get an error saying the file is open, and in bash I get a permission denied error, even when run as root, and sudo.

Is there some way to copy these hives, so I'll be able to do a complete system backup&restore with rsync easily? If not, are there some command line tools available for Windows, which can I use to copy the registry hives?

Comment: Copying the registry hive files isn't enough to backup your registry, there is no way to export and backup your registry, so it couldn't be imported into a new installation.  While you can import a hive file, having done it, it will not be imported into usable locations (it's only to view it).  The only way is to backup the installation itself.

Comment: @Ramhound And I guess, I'm unable to backup the installation using rsync, and need a backup program for that.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ramhound said - not going to work for you.

Plus this bug with [Win10 preventing Registry backup creation](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/10/31/windows-10-bug-prevents-registry-backup-creation/) (ghacks.net).

An excellent solution I've adopted for situations like this is Veeam's [Agent for Microsoft Windows FREE](https://www.veeam.com/windows-endpoint-server-backup-free.html)

I don't know why you are dual-booting, but I've been happy to not run Windows on bare metal for well over 10 years now. That's how I deal with backing up most of my (clients') windows machines (and when I can't virtualize, I use veeam).  They run virtually in Linux or Mac (or even FreeBSD, just for the hell of it).  Licensing - yada yada yada.

Pick a virtualiztion environment and learn it.  It is very freeing.